# How to transfer stripe amount to paypal

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, stripe-payments

Is any way to transfer stripe amount to PayPal.
OR
Is any way to transfer PayPal amount to Stripe.

Actually In some case, some customers have only credit card and merchant is providing PayPal OR some customers have only PayPal account and merchant is providing Stripe Payment.

So I want some API that full-fill such type of requirement.

Please provide me a way for cross platform transaction.

Comment: You might want to connect with their technical support team and get to know if they support any such thing.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to connect with technical support team get to know.

Comment: @Manraj Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can not transfer over cross platform as of now. Stripe provides withdrawal from connected bank account and PayPal doesn't allow traditional ACH deposits.

There no API from stripe for transfer to paypal and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for save my time but it should be. This is really a serious limitation that we can not transfer amount from stripe account to PayPal account and vice versa